# Explode at delimiter unless delimiter appears in quotes

Tags: php, csv, explode

I have the following string which I need to explode at the `,`:

```
$line = 'C13T110,E010,"WF2010/2510/2540 BK,C,M,Y PACK",0,99.99,EP,EP2,.000,'
```

The problem I have is that there is are a number of `,`'s within the description inside the quotes which are throwing out my resulting array.

How can I explode this string to output the following array:

```
[0] = C13T110
[1] = E010
[2] = "WF2010/2510/2540 BK,C,M,Y PACK"
[3] = 0
[4] = 99.99
[5] = EP
[6] = EP2
[7] = .000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to decode CSV format. Use `str_getcsv()`.

See [Documentation Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)